# Excel Product-If Function Without CSE Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have two columns: "type" in column A, and "price" in column B.

Conditional summing is easy enough: `=SUMIF(A1:A3, "Apples", "B1:B3")`

But what if I want to *multiply* all the instances where a condition is met? Is there a workaround to do so without using an array (meaning Ctrl+Shift+Enter) formula?

Comment: The answer to that is no.  All formulas that you will use to do that will be either native or forced array formula.  PRODUCT in itself is a native array formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PRODUCT` in conjunction with `FILTER` in the newest versions of Excel to get the desired result.

For example, `=PRODUCT(FILTER($B$1:$B$5, $A$1:$A$5="Apples")`

[image]